# binary data when transferring data across systems

Tags: c, binary, fwrite, fread

This quote is from CERT FIO09-C

> Portability is a concern when using the fread() and fwrite() functions
> across multiple, heterogeneous systems. In particular, it is never
> guaranteed that reading or writing of scalar data types such as
> integers, let alone aggregate types such as arrays or structures, will
> preserve the representation or value of the data. Implementations may
> differ in structure padding, floating-point model, number of bits per
> byte, endianness, and other attributes that cause binary data formats
> to be incompatible.
>
> ...
>
> Reading binary data that has a different format than expected may
> result in unintended program behavior.
>
> [CERT FIO09-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO09-C.+Be+careful+with+binary+data+when+transferring+data+across+systems)

From the Pearson C book I am reading:

> Although fread and fwrite read and write data, such as integers, in
> fixed-size rather than variable-size format, the data they handle are
> processed in computer “raw data” format (i.e., bytes of data) rather
> than in printf’s and scanf’s human-readable text format. Because the
> “raw” representation of data is system dependent, “raw data” may not
> be readable on other systems, or by programs produced by other
> compilers or with other compiler options.
>
> For more portable file representations, consider using text files or a function
> library that can handle the differences in binary file representations
> across platforms.

I search the web, but I cannot find the C libraries that book mentioned. I tried many different keywords, but nothing is popping up. Don't know if he meant I have to write my own library, or there are libraries out there.

Does anyone know of any C library that can handle transferring binary data across systems such as files written with fwrite?

Comment: The most popular format these days is JSON. Search for JSON C library.

Comment: A compact format used by NFS is [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation)

Comment: I thought JSON was javascript

Comment: Did not know there was a JSON C

Comment: JSON is used in many languages, that's the point. PHP has `json_encode()`, Python has `json.dumps()`.

Comment: The only relationship with JavaScript is that the format is a subset of JavaScript literal notation.

Comment: Thanks, I look at JSON C and XDR in detail later.

Comment: There are JSON libraries in C, but I don't think JSON addresses the OP's question about libraries for *binary* data exchange.

Comment: But in any case, @Manny_Mar, I think you may have misunderstood.  The Pearson book is not talking about libraries that somehow handle *general* binary data "such as files written with fwrite".  It is talking about libraries for use *instead of* `fwrite`.

Comment: @John Ok, I was not sure which he meant.

Comment: json, xml, ... are formatted character strings and do not handle binaries. usually byte streams are compatible between most of the systems. one needs to read/write those. checke for byte buffers.